# android. best principle to detect media buttons in api 23 and later

Tags: android, button, media

I have an issue with power button. Is there a way to catch system events for media buttons. So that I can create a app to wake up phone by pressing vol key.

Comment: Can you pls make the ques more clear.

Comment: I need wake up by volume buttons, because I have breaked power button.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes. For example, in same roms was this function in settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run command below commands

> adb shell
>
> cd system/usr/keylayout
>
> vi sci-keypad.kl

edit key 115 as POWER instead of VOLUME_UP

Comment: Work by editing other file. Can I make it   that the volume also works?